# Get VirtualPath of a Route

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, routes, asp.net-routing

I have the following Route:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteTest",
            "Path1/Path2/Path3/{PARAM1}-{PARAM2}/{OPTPARAM}",
            "~/MyPath/Default.aspx",
            True,
            New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.OPTPARAM = Nothing}),
            Nothing,
            Nothing)
```

I know the value of the two non-optional parameters: `PARAM1` (let's say `20`) and `PARAM2` (let's say `30`).

How to use `Route.GetVirtualPath` to build the path in my ASPX.VB page?
The result should be `Path1/Path2/Path3/20-30/`. Ideally I don't want to work directly with the string, replacing the values (specially because there are optional values like `OPTPARAM`.

Comment: Why do you need to use `Route.GetVirtualPath`? Would `Page.GetRouteUrl` work for you?

Comment: @Andrei That's what I was looking for! Thank you!